# How to load ACL / bjyauthorize once user is authenticated?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, acl, bjyauthorize

I have installed ZendFramework bjyauthorize.
I also installed zfcuser, but I dont want to use that.
I have my other authenication module. 
I would like to know how I can trigger or load the bjyauthorize roles/ACL, after user gets authenticated.

Is this a correct provider?

```
namespace Firewall\Provider\Identity;

//use BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity;
//use BjyAuthorize\Exception\InvalidRoleException;
//use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
//use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
//use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
//use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
//use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\RoleInterface;
//use Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session as SessionStorage;
//use BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface;
//use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
//use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
//use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService; 
//
//class Myprovider implements  ProviderInterface {
//    
//    
//
//public function setDbAdapter();
//public function getDbAdapter();
//public function getIdentityRoles();
//public function getDefaultRole();
//public function getRoles();
//
//}



use BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

class Myprovider implements ProviderInterface
{
//    public function getDefaultRole()
//    {
//        $aTest = "test";
//        return new Debug();
//    }

    public function getIdentityRoles()
    {
        $oIdentity = $this->getIdentity();

        $aRoles = [];
        if(!empty($oIdentity))
        {
            $aRoles = $oIdentity->getRoles();
        }

        return $aRoles;
    }

    protected $authService;

    public function __construct(AuthenticationService $authService)
    {
        $this->authService = $authService;
    }
    public function setAdapter($adapter)
    {
        return $this->authService->setAdapter($adapter);
    }        
    public function getAdapter()
    {
        return $this->authService->getAdapter();
    }

    public function getStorage()
    {
        return $this->authService->getStorage();
    }

    public function getIdentity()
    {
        return $this->authService->getIdentity();
    }

    public function clearIdentity()
    {
        return $this->authService->clearIdentity();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems my question is not clear! How can I implement bjyAuthorize with my Authentication module? How can I get the ACL object from database? What function/method provides the logged in user's roles?

Answer (score 0):

bjyAuthorize doesn't directly interact with your authentication module. It just needs the role of the currently signed in user. It gets that through the identity provider. So you should extend the ProviderInterface for the identity provider to return the roles that belong to the currently signed in user.

[Identity provider interface](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/master/src/BjyAuthorize/Provider/Identity/ProviderInterface.php)

You should probably also change (or make your own) the default role provider to return the roles that you defined for your authentication module

Comment: How it identify the signed in user? Is it id field from database? Some more explanation is appreciated. I tried $myProvider->getIdentityRoles() method, but it shows all the roles. How can I extract roles that belong to one user only?

Comment: @user1322977 You should return all the roles of the current user. You can get the current user from your authentication module. In your example authentication service and call the getIdentity to get the current user. After that it depends on how and where you store the rules for the users. Of they are in the same table as the user. Than the probably are part of your user model and you can get them from the returned object. Otherwise you should look up the user from somewhere else with the Id from the current user